# Обновление Android Studio до версии 2.0 повлекло за собой "ужас"

Tags: android-studio, render, android-layout-inflater

После обновления были некоторые проблемы которые смог исправить, но вот какая осталась, не знаю, как решить:

[image: проблемы рендеринга]

Результат **Show Exception**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
>       at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
>       at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:134)
>       at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:127)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:170)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:247)
>       at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:171)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:838)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:229)
>       at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
>       at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:510)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:498)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:610)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:607)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:359)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:607)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:629)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:652)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1700(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:594)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
>       at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:589)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
>       at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
>       at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>       at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: Студия ругается на то, что вам надо тему из библиотеки поддержки использовать. При этом, если проблема только в предпросмоторщике, то вместо попыток её исправить лучше отказаться от использования оного. Он не нужен. Ещё можно откатиться до 1.5. версии студии. Про глюки версии 2 по несколько вопросов в день тут задают.

Comment: А как откатиться на 1.5 ? И да дело только в просмотрщике.

Comment: Как откатываться, я не знаю) Наверное можно поискать установочник нужной версии... Ну или забить - ведь если дело только в просмоторщике, то это отличная возможность отказаться от его использоания)

Comment: Я бы рад но это блин не html верстать, тут некоторые отличия есть поэтому путаюсь ))

Comment: Ну, тут гораздо проще же, чем html) Да и в любом случае просмоторщик дико, **ДИКО** глючный. Намучаетесь с ним. Он очень часто неправильно показывает. Особенно что-то более сложное чем текстовое поле с отступом слева.

Comment: Вполне возможно )) Вот когда привыкнут быть без просмотрщика тогда и откажусь ))) Сейчас видимо нужно откатываться ))